# to pass action name at dynamically it is possible?

Tags: struts2

am using struts2, i need to do multi language option, language option i have put in header of the all pages.May i know, to pass action name at dynamically it is possible in struts.xml file.action name is dynamic or static? can anybody help me please, advance in thanks.

for example:In the struts.xml file

$(curActionName)

Answer (score 1):

firstly action can be selected dynamically by using the wild card method. this tutorial will help you understand wild card mappings.
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/wildcard-mappings.html

However since you are talking about many language support if all you want is rendering same page in different languages you will not need dynamic action as struts already has an elegant internationalization feature where you just have to maintain properties file for each language. this makes it easier to maintain your website.you can study more of this here.
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/localization.html